# Multiple GlusterFS backup servers

Tags: mount, glusterfs

I've setup an arbitrated replicated volume like this

```
gluster volume create gvol \
    replica 3 \
    arbiter 1 \
    host1:/opt/brick/vol1 host2:/opt/brick/vol1 host3:/opt/arb/vol1 \
    host4:/opt/brick/vol2 host5:/opt/brick/vol2 host6:/opt/arb/vol2
```

and now I'd like to mount it on the client, using its backup servers. It seems that the backupvolfile-servers (plural) directive is now deprecated, which allowed to specify multiple servers (e.g., `backupvolfile-servers=host2:host4:host5`). Now, it seems that the backupvolfile-server (singular) directive only allows for one backup server to be specified (e.g., `backupvolfile-server=host2`).

Is there still a way to specify multiple backup servers?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that backup-volfile-servers does the trick.

Ref: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.4/html/administration_guide/chap-accessing_data_-_setting_up_clients

Comment: There are a few synonyms for this option.  Please check `man mount.glusterfs` for your version/platform.